# is it possible to use webdriver/Selenium to get current tab which user actually view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to check/monitor the tab that user using. But i found that the driver alway only monitor the first tab since browser open.

I tried to use this

```
driver.current_window_handle
```

It shows the windows name but it is not exactly the tab user actually use. It is always the first tab unless i do  `driver.swith_to_window`
Also, i tried to use

```
handles = driver.window_handles
```

then do this for each handle in handles

```
driver.swith_to_window(handle)
```

But this will interrupt user's operation as the browser will switch tab one by one.

Is it possible to get the window handle, title or index of the current tab user actually view by webdriver or selenium?

The scenario :

1. python open browser
2. user open tab 1, tab2, tab3 and access web site
3. user views tab2
4. selenium get the data from tab2
5. user views tab1
6. selenium get the data from tab1
7. user views tab3
8. selenium get the data from tab3  ...etc

Currently i can only get the data from tab1. If user views tab2, then selenium do nothing unless i switch_to_window. But i don't know which one tab is user viewing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of switching tab one by one, just give the required tab number directly.

```
driver.switch_to_window(1)
```

//1 being the tab id

Comment: Yes, i do want to switch to the window which user is using. However i don't know how to get the tab index or handle from the tab user actually view

Comment: could you please elucidate what you meant by 'if user view tab1/2/..'. better with code.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why not switch to the tab directly since you may know the id

It will be much faster than looping

driver.switch_to_window(handle)

Comment: Yes, i do want to switch to the window which user is using. However i don't know how to get the tab index or handle from the tab user actually view.
When i get window_handles array, i don't know which one is that user see

Comment: Is this always a fix tab ? If it is , there is a high likely hood this handle is fixed (i need to double check on this)

Comment: sorry. what means fix tab? don't understand

Comment: What I mean is that the handle may always be constant. So you can always closed that tab by same handle

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

To switch windows use `.switch_to.window` instead `.swith_to_window` like this:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_window_handle)
```

`[1]` > please replace with the index you want.

To get title use:

```
print(driver.title)
```

To get index current tab use:

```
print(driver.window_handles.index(driver.current_window_handle))
```

Or use `for each` loop like the below example (refers to your scenario):

```
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.execute_script('window.open("https://yahoo.com");')
driver.execute_script('window.open("https://gmail.com");')

for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(handle)
    print(driver.window_handles.index(handle))
    print(handle)
    print(driver.title)
```